# Sequelize, many unique composite keys using same field

Tags: sequelize.js, composite-key, unique-key

If I am designing a table containing the following fields 
column_one, column_two, column_three, and I want the combination (column_one:column_two) to be unique, I would do the following:

```
column_one: { type: DataTypes.INTEGER, unique: 'composite_one'},
column_one: { type: DataTypes.INTEGER, unique: 'composite_one'},
column_three: { type: DataTypes.INTEGER}
```

What if I need two unique combinations, both including one of the fields? Ex: (column_one:column_two) and (column_one:column_three) must both be unique, though (column_two:column_three) can be repeated

In theory it would be something like:

```
column_one: { type: DataTypes.INTEGER, unique: 'composite_one', unique: 'composite_two'},
column_one: { type: DataTypes.INTEGER, unique: 'composite_one'},
column_three: { type: DataTypes.INTEGER, unique: 'composite_two'}
```

This is not a join table, and I do not want to use any raw queries.

Also, column_one must create unique combinations with 2 and 3, but it does not mean that column one, two and three must create a single unique combination.

In case the explanation is not clear, I am giving an example:

```
column_one ----- column_two ---- column_three
-11---------------12----------------13-------
-11---------------12----------------14-------
-18---------------12----------------15-------
```

is not a valid set of data, because there are two rows with (column_one: column_two) = (11:12)

But

```
column_one ----- column_two ---- column_three
-11---------------12----------------13-------
-11---------------17----------------12-------
-18---------------12----------------15-------
-11---------------12----------------15-------
```

is a valid set of data

Answer (score 2):

I managed to solve this using indexes. [This is a link](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/manual/tutorial/models-definition.html#indexes) to the full documentation from sequelize docs. As for the implementation, in the model I added the following code after the field:

```
indexes: [
    { fields: ['column_one', 'column_two'], unique: true },
    { fields: ['column_one', 'column_three'], unique: true }
]
```

A similar approach is used if I would like to migrate the changes of the model to an existing database:

```
queryInterface.addIndex('epg_data', ['column_one', 'column_two'], {unique: true})
queryInterface.addIndex('epg_data', ['column_one', 'column_three'], {unique: true})
```

Answer (score 1):

Over your migrations, you can use sequelize `addConstraint` method

From the [Docs](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/manual/tutorial/migrations.html#addconstraint-tablename-attributes-options-)

```
 queryInterface.addConstraint('Users', ['email', 'name'], { type: 'unique', name: 'custom_unique_constraint_name' });
```

Comment: The issue with this solution is addressed in  https://github.com/sequelize/cli/issues/462.